# Ruby - TryRuby example " All together now "

Tags: ruby

Complete Ruby novice here,
I was going through the [Examples](https://try.ruby-lang.org/) quite smoothly until I reached this section named "All together now".
So the provided code is :

```
  def count_plays(year)
  s = get_shakey

  s["William Shakespeare"]
    .select { |k, v|
      v["finished"] == year
    }.each { |key, val|
      puts val["title"]
    }.count
end

puts count_plays(0)
```

Which outputs :

```
0 
Answer for the year 1591 should be 4
```

Hint at the end of the example states:

> There is another possibility for chaining here. See that lonely line s
> = get_shakey. You could add the [“William Shakespeare”].select { |k, v| at the end of get_shakey (no dot needed in this case).

But I could not figure out how add this correctly as the I get no output from it.

Any help and tips for solving this is appreciated.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is read the provided code and realize that the argument for `count_plays()` is the year you want to check on.  In other words, change the 0 to 1591, and you'll start seeing output.  You shouldn't start tweaking the code with chaining until you get it working in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

All this is saying is, instead of this:

```
  s = get_shakey

  s["William Shakespeare"]
    .select { |k, v|
      v["finished"] == year
    }.each { |key, val|
      puts val["title"]
    }.count
```

You do this:

```
  get_shakey["William Shakespeare"]
    .select { |k, v|
      v["finished"] == year
    }.each { |key, val|
      puts val["title"]
    }.count
```

All I did was replace the `s["William Shakespeare"]` with `get_shakey["William Shakespeare"]`, because `s` is the same as `get_shakey`. It's just trying to show that you can either write things as separate expressions (using variables along the way), or combine them into a single expression if you desire.